# exporting es6 modules for mvc5 project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am attempting to set up webpack for an mvc5 project (not core).  everything is working fine. except for referencing modules in the scripts of cshtml pages.  for example in my layout page I have.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

in main.js

```
import Person from './person';

var person = new Person("David", 20);
person.speak();
```

and person.js

```
export default class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    speak() {
        console.log(`Hi I'm ${this.name} and ${this.age} years old and I am awesome`);
    }
}
```

this works fine when I run the app I see the output in my console.

however trying to reference people in say index.cshtml is giving me problems.

I changed main.js to.

```
module.exports = {
    Person: require('./person'),
};
```

and in the view I attempt to reference person

in index.cshtml (which is using the layout page)

```
<script>
        var person = new Person("David", 20);
        person.speak();
    </script>
```

I receive

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined
>       at Index:64

Comment: Are you trying to access `Person` even before the file has loaded?

Comment: don't think so. just in case I wrapped it in document ready  at top of  _layout I have    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/build/bundle.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)     and in index.cshtml           @section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var person = new Person("David", 20);
            person.speak();
        });
    </script>
}